# From $f(x)=g(x)$ to $x=a_1,...a_n$ only extraneous solutions can arise.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic

Question: Does $f(x)=g(x) \implies x=a,a_2,..a_n$ mean that we must have $x=a_1$, or $x=a_2$, or $x=a_4$.

I think the answer is no. I can take $x+1=x$ then $(x+1)^2=x^2$ and thus then we have $x=-0.5$.

I think this is because we must assume a solution exists before operating on both sides, taking functions on both sides? Is that correct? Also this begs the question: does this only mean we have that $x$ doesn't exist or that $x=a_1$ or $x=a_2$...$a_n=x$. So that when we go from $f(x)=0$ to $x=..$ we can only get extraneous solutions but not missing solutions? What about if we get an infinite number of solutions? Can someone please explain, thanks in advance.

---

**Edit**: does this mean that in the context of geometry if we have "A is B" and by logic deduce this $\implies$ that $x \equiv b$. That we have only shown that we can other have:

$$x \equiv b$$

Or

$$x$$

Does not exist.

I guess that means to say something about the object you are trying prove, you must prove it exists. (Which I think is just taken for granted in geometry classes, because I never proved that objects exist, I just proved certain things about the objects assuming they existed).

Comment: $x+1=x \implies x=-0.5$ only means that if $x+1=x$ has a solution, then the solution must be $-0.5$. It does not mean that $-0.5$ is a solution.

Think about this: $x^2=4 \implies x$ is even. But not every even number has square equals to 1.